# Show that $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ has exactly one zero

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Show that $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R,\ x\mapsto e^x-x^2-2x-2$ has exactly one zero.

First of all, using the IVT it is very easy to show that at least one zero must exist, i.e. in the interval $[2,100]$. However, I find it tricky to show that there can't be another zero. Using the taylor series of $e^x$ one can easily see that because $$f'(x)=-1-x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\dots>0,\quad \text{when } x>2,$$ the function is strictly monotone and therefor can't have another zero in $[2,\infty)$. But how can I show that it doesn't have a zero in $(-\infty,2)$? I can't seem to find a proper mathematical way to show this.

Comment: Idea: with the help of $f'$, find the intervals on which $f$ is monotone. For each such interval, you only need to check one of the end points.

Comment: @WhatsUp I tried that. But as far as I can see, one can't compute the extrema analytically so there is no way I figure out these intervals.

Comment: You don't have to get exact closed expressions for the extrema. It would suffice if you can just determine the number of extrema and some intervals in which they lie. This turns out to be studying the zeros of $f'$. If needed, it will further require you to study the zeros of $f''$, etc. But eventually it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f'(x) = 0$ occurs when $e^x = 2x + 2$. By plugging in $x = 0$, we see that the line $y = 2x + 2$ is not below the convex curve $y = e^x$, so $e^x = 2x + 2$ has two solutions, call them $x_1$ and $x_2$ where $x_1 < x_2$. These are the points where $f'(x) = 0$. $f(x)$ is increasing for $x < x_1$ and $x > x_2$, and is decreasing for $x_1 < x < x_2$.

For $x = x_1$ or $x_2$, we have  $f(x) = e^x - x^2 - 2x - 2 < 
e^x - 2x - 2 = 0$. So $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ are negative. As a result, since $f(x)$ is increasing for $x < x_1$ and decreasing for $x_1 < x < x_2$, $f(x)$ cannot have any zeroes for $x < x_2$.

Since $f(x)$ is increasing on $x > x_2$, it can have at most one zero for $x > x_2$. Since $f(x_2) < 0$ and $f(x) > 0$ for large enough $x$, there is in fact one zero of $f(x)$ for $x > x_2$.

We conclude $f(x)$ has exactly one zero, occurring for some $x > x_2$.

Comment: The observation $f(x)<f'(x)$ for $x\neq 0$ is very neat! Thanks for that very nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

We have $$f(x)=e^x-x^2-2x-2$$ $$f'(x)=e^x-2x-2$$ $$f''(x)=e^x-2$$ $$f'''(x)=e^x$$

That means that $f'(x)$ has a global minimum at $x=\ln(2)$. One root of $f'(x)$ is between $-1$ and $0$ , the other one between $1$ and $2$

$f(x)$ is negative for $x=-1,0,1,2$

$f(x)$ is increasing outside the interval $[-1,2]$ and decreasing in the interval $[0,2]$. In the interval $(-1,0)$ , we have $|x^2+2x+2|\ge 1$, hence $f(x)$ is negative in this interval. $f(x)$ tends to $-\infty$ , if $x$ tends to $-\infty$. That means that $f(x)$ is negative for $x\le 2$. For $x\ge 2$, $f(x)$ is strictly increasing and tends to $\infty$ , if $x$ tends to $\infty$.

Hence $f(x)$ has exactly one real root.

Comment: Why is $f$ decreasing inside $[-1, 2]$? As far as I can tell, this is wrong. $f$ has a local maximum around $-0.768$.

Comment: It is actually wrong. I plotted it.

Comment: @Schach21 However the upvotes will probably keep this wrong answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Prove that f   is negative for $x<0$  then prove that it attains zero derivative at one and only one point for positive $x$  .  
(The function at the point must be negative because f is monotonic for x greater than equal to 2 ) and since f(2) is negative we will agin reach a contradiction if the point is not negative due to Rolle’s THM) .
 Now if f had another root then we would again reach a contradiction due to Rolle’s thm since f is negative for x<0)

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$f(x) = 0 \iff e^x-1 = (x+1)^2.$$

Clearly $0$ isn't a root. Notice that $(x+1)^2 \geq 0$ while $e^x - 1 < 0$ when $x< 0$ so there are no roots on $(-\infty,0].$

Notice that at any given root $x > 0$ we have

$$f'(x) = e^x - 2x - 2 = f(x) + x^2 = 0 + x^2 >0.$$
This means that $f$ (which is continuous) is strictly increasing on an open neighbourhood of each of it's roots so it can't have several roots.